# What does it mean to identify a monetary policy shock

Tags: monetary-policy

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When someone asks you to identify monetary policy shock in data they are asking for you to identify (using some econometric/statistical analysis) whether there was some sudden change in monetary policy (e.g. monetary policy suddenly becoming contractionary or expansionary) and its effects on macroeconomy (e.g. GDP/inflation). [Bachman et al 2021](https://www.nber.org/papers/w29572) is an example of identifying monetary shocks.